# PHP - Get complete value of query string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently using CodeIgniter. It seems i cannot get the complete value of a query string that has this value:

```
mywebsite.com/home?path=Announcement/1036_Write-up Montessori J & D 2017]1504509916.pdf
```

I tried using `$_GET['path']` and `$this->input->get('path')` but both didn't work.

Actual Behavior:
path only has this value: `Announcement/1036_Write-up Montessori J`

Expected Behavior:
path should have the entire path value: `Announcement/1036_Write-up Montessori J & D 2017]1504509916.pdf`

Comment: Are you typing that URL in? However it's being generated, you need to URL encode the value. It should be `Announcement%2F1036_Write-up%20Montessori%20J%20%26%20D%202017%5D1504509916.pdf`. The most important part is encoding the ampersand from `&` to `%26`

Comment: You need to `encode` your url while you redirecting it. In URL `&` separate params thats why you are not getting entire value

Comment: I'd also recommend using safer filenames in and of themselves. If your file is really called `1036_Write-up Montessori J & D 2017]1504509916.pdf`, it seems strange to have both spaces and underscores. I've also never seen a `]` in a filename before. Rename your file to something like `1036_writeup_montessori_j_and_d_2017_1504509916.pdf` and you won't encounter encoding problems ;)

Comment: the value is actually from a user. i cannot control how they will name the file

Comment: how should i do the encode?

Comment: i tried urldecode(urlencode($path)) - works in desktop browser but not in mobile browser. The value stops at the letter "J"

Comment: just used urlencode($path). why you using for 2 times.

Comment: You can use  current_url() function to get the URL and then use basename() function to get the file name.

Comment: try urlencode(string)